# Unfair 3 Sided Dice

Tags: probability

If you roll an unfair 3 sided dice where

Side 1 has probability $p_1$
Side 2 has probability $p_2$
Side 3 has probability $p_3$

How can you find a formula that the 8th 3 will be rolled on the 10th roll? I see that this question was asked before, its a good start, but there was no answer on this.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this?  What have you done?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To get the $8th$ $3$ on the $10th$ roll, we must get $7$ $3$'s in the first $9$ rolls and then a $3$ on the $10th$ roll. Use the negative binomial distribution with $n$ trials given $k$ successes:

$$P(X=n)={n-1 \choose k-1}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Comment: this makes sense  - but no probability is given. So how would you solve it from here? This is about how far I made it?

Comment: It seems to me that the question requests an equation. There is no way to get a numerical answer unless $p_3$ is given. If it was fair, it would be $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: makes sense. So is the above answer you gave correct? Or is there still some work to be done?

Comment: Yes, other than identifying $n$ and $k$. I'll leave it to you to identify $n$, $k$ and $p$ where $p$ is presumably an unknown.

Comment: so is n - 10 rolls? k - 8? and p is just p?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You might want to replace $p$ with $p_3$ for clarity.

Comment: thank you. I was having a tough time trying to formulate an actual answer I lost sight of this.